# how to refresh JWT Token after username update in NestJS?

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I've been using Passport JWT for Auth and the payload for signing is username and seller.
Now the issue is that every time i update username and tries to fetch userdetails it gives 401. So i'm looking for a way to handle this gracefully using passport jwt in nestjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the user id and the seller id as payload? These values won't change and therefore the token stays valid even when the username changes